# Sending to Multiple Emails in PHP

Tags: php, email

There is something off in this php, after the Reply-To email address in an email - I am getting a Cc afterward and it's not getting send to both the CC & BCC. This tells me I am making an error somewhere in this code and it's probably really obvious.

```
// Create email 
$email_subject = "Subject";
$email_body = "You have received interest. \n\n".
              "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \n";
$headers = "From: 1-email@email.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
$headers .= "Cc: 2-email@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: 3-email@email.com\r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // Post message
```

Comment: You need `\r\n` after Reply-To too.

Comment: Also on the "From: line it should be \r\n to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the headers to have \r\n at the end of each line. The last line does not require it though.

```
// Create email 
$email_subject = "Subject";
$email_body = "You have received interest. \n\n".
              "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \n";
$headers = "From: 1-email@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: 2-email@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: 3-email@email.com";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // Post message
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

```
// Create email 
$email_subject = "Subject";
$email_body = "You have received interest. \n\n".
          "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \n";
$headers = "From: 1-email@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: 2-email@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: 3-email@email.com\r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // Post message
```